# Understanding fit_generator (steps_per_epoch), validation_steps, evaluate_generator (Steps) & predict_generator (steps)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

I am new in using keras for my project. I have been working with `generator` in my model.

I am literally confused what value should i input

> 1) In fit_generator : steps_per_epoch & validation_steps ?
>
> 2) evaluate_generator : steps ?
>
> 3) predict_generator : steps ?

I have referred [keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/) and few other [stack1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943675/meaning-of-validation-steps-in-keras-sequential-fit-generator-parameter-list), [stack2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47405/what-to-set-in-steps-per-epoch-in-keras-fit-generator) questions. I cannot able to understand. **Better I can provide the example of my data shape what I am currently working and follow my questions accordingly. Also, please correct if my understanding is wrong**

```
model.fit_generator(trainGen, steps_per_epoch=25, epochs = 100, validation_data=ValGen, validation_steps= 4)
```

**Q1:** For every epoch, there were `25 steps`. For each step `trainGen` yields a tuple of shape `(244*100*4, 244*100*2)` and perform training.

> What will be my `batch_size` and `batches` if my `steps_per_epoch is 25` ?

**Q2:**
I understood that `val_acc and val_loss` will be calculated at the end of `25th step of the an epoch`. I choose my `validation_steps = 4`. So `ValGen` yields a tuple of shape `(30*100*4, 30*100*2) 4 times at the end of 25th step of an epoch`

> I have chosen arbitrarily `validation_steps = 4.` But how to choose
>   correct number of `validation_steps` ? How does `val_loss & val_acc`
>   calculated ? (calculate the mean 4 times either as single batch or
>   using batch_size)

**Q3:**
Say for example in `evaluate_generator & predict_generator`, my Generator yields a tuple shape `(30*100*4, 30*100*2)` for both.

> How to choose the correct number for `steps` argument for both
>   `evaluate_generator & predict_generator` ? In keras document it is mentioned as Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from generator before stopping ? `In my case what will the batches of samples ?`

If any additional information required let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps are not a parameter that you "choose", you can compute it as:

```
steps = number of samples / batch size
```

So here the only parameter that you are free to choose is the batch size, which is chosen to a value where the model does not run out of memory while training. Typical values are between 32 and 64.

For the training set, you use the number of samples of the training set and divide it for the training batch size, and for the validation set, you divide the number of samples in the validation set with the validation batch size. Both batch sizes can be equal.

This applies to all functions that use generators.

Comment: Whether, can I choose my batch_size be less than 32. say if i choose batch_size = 15, what will be effect (both positive and negative) during training and validation ?

Comment: @Mari Small batch sizes have the effect of reducing performance (training takes longer), and the gradient estimate is more noisy, which can cause learning problems (loss decrease is noisy).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy How about the validation_steps in Question 2?