# steps_per_epoch and validation_steps for infinite Dataset in Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a huge dataset of csv files having a volume of around 200GB. I don't know the total number of records in the dataset. I'm using [make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset) to create a PreFetchDataset generator.

I'm facing problem when Tensorflow complains to specify steps_per_epoch and validation_steps for infinite dataset....

1. How can I specify the steps_per_epoch and validation_steps?
2. Can I pass these parameters as the percentage of total dataset size?
3. Can I somehow avoid these parameters as I want my whole dataset to
   be iterated for each epoch?

I think [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943675/meaning-of-validation-steps-in-keras-sequential-fit-generator-parameter-list) thread answer the case when we know to total number of data records in advance.

Here is a screenshot from documentation. But I'm not getting it properly.
[image: screenshot]

What does the last line mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no other option than iterating through your entire dataset.

```
ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset('myfile.csv', batch_size=16, num_epochs=1)

for ix, _ in enumerate(ds, 1):
    pass

print('The total number of steps is', ix)
```

Don't forget the `num_epochs` argument.